# How to create a horizontal carousel view in android?

Tags: android, carousel

In my Android application I want to implement Carousel for 7 views.

My carousel has to show like the 1st image in this [link](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2014/02/11/building-a-paged-carousel)

[image: carousel].

I have checked out couple of links and some demo examples also like this one [svn-link](http://android-carousel-demo.googlecode.com/svn/CarouselDemo), but

1st of all its for even number of views, where i have only 7 views

secondly it adds all its content from attribute xml, I would prefer adding the views by code,

and I don't need a complete circular carousel, just an Arc shaped is fine with me.

Presently I have used coverflow, but experiencing too many bugs which is not so easy to solve.

Please help me with some demo, or example of carousel, simpler is better.

Or if using any other procedure I can show my list this way, any kind of ideas or hint is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hi i have answered hope those links will help you!!

Comment: @ari have you designed this i need help ?

Comment: I did it a long time ago with some hacks, you should be able to do this a little easier now I think.

Answer (score 2):

See this coverflow widget, It's works like a listView so it is very simple to use :

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html

Steps :

- Import library classes on your classpath
- Instead of ListView, use CoverFlow;
- Write your coverflowAdapter, here it will contains only images (see sample code from link)
- Set the adapter to your coverflow

Hope it helps !

Comment: post the relevant part of the link in your post. link only answers are discouraged

Comment: Ok I'am editing my answer