# what is this image gallery called in android

Tags: java, android, android-gallery

I am planning to build this kind of a image view in android i could use your help in how to get started.

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Carousel](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Carousel+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=2jKJVIzmBoKVuAT6zIDoDw)

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ can you provide this as an answer as  your answer is correct and would like to select that

Comment: I added answer, happy coding :)

Comment: Thanks same to you, but how do you keep up with these constant changes can you suggest a few good blogs to get me started on these designs

Comment: I just learn by googling.. when some requirement is there, I google what is my best option :)

Comment: hell of a way to teach someone to fish :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its called [Carousel](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Carousel+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=2jKJVIzmBoKVuAT6zIDoDw)

See this: [carousel layout android](https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/)

If you want 3 D Carousel, you can see [this post](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/146145/Android-3D-Carousel)

You would need to create a custom class for your images, which extends ImageView.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
public class CarouselImageView extends ImageView 
    implements Comparable<carouselimageview> {

    private int index;
    private float currentAngle;
    private float x;
    private float y;
    private float z;
    private boolean drawn;

    public CarouselImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }   

    public CarouselImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CarouselImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public int compareTo(CarouselImageView another) {
        return (int)(another.z – this.z);
    }

}
```

You can customize the code as per requirement as to make a horizontal carousel or the vertical one.

Hope this helps.

Comment: alternatively just for future reference this library is also there https://github.com/moondroid/CoverFlow

Answer (score 0):

Extract from another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21905049/how-to-create-a-horizontal-carousel-view-in-android)

See this coverflow widget, It's works like a listView so it is very simple to use :

http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/01/android-coverflow-widget.html

Steps :

- Import library classes on your classpath
- Instead of ListView, use CoverFlow
- Write your coverflowAdapter, here it will contains only images (see
  sample code from link)
- Set the adapter to your coverflow

Hope it helps !